# Bitwise Operators Left Shift

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I'm confused with bitwise operators. Whenever I do 99(0110 0011) << 2, the answer is 396. My understanding with left shifts is that add two 0s on the right side. So my answer would be 140(1000 1100) and not 396. Why is the answer 396 for 99 << 2 in Java?

Comment: By "adding two zeros", it literally shifts the binary to the left twice, hence the name of the operator. The numbers don't drop off the left side for small  integers

Answer (score 1):

You are only showing 8 bits, but an `int` is 32 bits.

```
byte    8 bits
short  16 bits
int    32 bits
long   64 bits
```

Integer calculations in Java are coerced to `int` or `long`, so even if your `99` value *was* a `byte`, the result of `((byte)99) << 2` is still an `int`.

```
                              0110 0011 = 99  (byte)
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1000 1100 = 396 (int)
```

Now, you can always cast it back to a `byte`, which will discard all high-order bits:

```
(byte)(99 << 2) = (byte)0b10001100 = (byte)0x8C = -116
```

Or you can discard the high-order bits while keeping it an `int`:

```
(99 << 2) & 0xFF = 0b10001100 = 0x0000008C = 140
```

Comment: @JonathanNelsonCastillo If this was the answer you were looking for, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, so others can see that your question is been adequately answered.

Answer (score 0):

Because a Java `int` is a signed 32-bit quantity (not 8 bits) and a bitwise left shift by 2 (`<< 2`) is the same as `* 4`. You can see this like

```
int i = 99;
System.out.printf("  %s (%d)%n", Integer.toBinaryString(i), i);
i <<= 2;
System.out.printf("%s (%d)%n", Integer.toBinaryString(i), i);
```

Output is

```
  1100011 (99)
110001100 (396)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes a lot of sense now. :)